# Possible add color palette for a block's inner div instead of outer?

Tags: block-editor

I'm developing a block that has a layout where the color should be applied to an inner div, not the outer block container. Is that possible?

If I add color support, it will add it to the outer container, like this:
[image]

But I want the color added to an inner div to create this:

[image]

I know I could override this with CSS, but I'm wondering if it's possible to add a color palette picker to an inner div.

My current setup in block.json looks like this:

```js
    "supports": {
        "color": {
            "text": true,
            "background": true
        }
    },
    "attributes": {
        "backgroundColor": {
      "type": "string",
      "default": "mist"
   },
```

I want the user to be able to choose from the theme palette without it being on block container.

My new code, which works, but I'd rather have it add a class like 'has-x-background-color' instead of an inline style using the hex code. I think getColorObjectByColorValue is the answer, but I can't figure out how to use it.

```js
import { __ } from "@wordpress/i18n";
import {
    useBlockProps,
    InspectorControls,
    useSetting,
    useInnerBlocksProps,
} from "@wordpress/block-editor";

import { PanelBody, ColorPalette } from "@wordpress/components";

export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {
    const { bgColor } = attributes;

    const innerBlocksProps = useInnerBlocksProps({
        style: {
            backgroundColor: bgColor,
        },
    });

    return (
        <>
            <InspectorControls>
                <PanelBody>
                    <p>Background Color</p>
                    <ColorPalette
                        value={bgColor}
                        colors={[...useSetting("color.palette")]}
                        onChange={(value) => setAttributes({ bgColor: value })}
                    />
                </PanelBody>
            </InspectorControls>

            <div {...useBlockProps()}>
                <p>testing testing</p>
                <div {...innerBlocksProps} />
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: you could also keep it as it, make the div smaller, and the image larger so it breaks out of the div, otherwise what you're asking for is going to require custom code to add an additional attribute and UI for picking and storing the colour then applying it

Comment: @TomJNowell I know there's the color picker component, but do you know if you can add an attribute, like you mentioned, and have it so they can pick from the theme's color palette? The colorpicker looks like it only adds an option to add a custom color, like a hex code.

Comment: I've figured out how to change an inner div's color using an attribute. BUT, it's by adding an inline style. I'd rather have it add a class with the color slug (like how "has-colorname-background-color" is added on a block's container. Adding my current code. 

I think using getColorObjectByColorValue is the answer, but I can't figure out how to use it.